# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException reading from excel file

Tags: java, excel-2010, indexoutofboundsexception, jxl

I am trying to read the following data from an Excel sheet

[image: Data]

With the following code

```
import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

 public String readUsernameFromExcel() {
        File src = new File("C:/filepath.xls");

        try {

            Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(src);
            Sheet sh1 = wb.getSheet(0);
            Cell a2 = sh1.getCell(0, 2);
            data1 = a2.getContents().trim();


        } catch (BiffException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return data1;

    }
```

So when I try and get the cell `0,1` I can pick up the username `1000483` just fine. But when I try to read `0,2` and I get `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2`.

What I'm trying to do is read data from an excel sheet return it as a `String` and then pass it in to login my application. But it seems when I try `0,2` I'm going outside of what is expected. I've tried a few things such as a for loop

```
 for (int rows = 0; rows < sh1.getRows(); rows++) {
 Sheet sh1 = wb.getSheet(0);
            Cell a2 = sh1.getCell(0, 2);

}
```

I understand the first number is the column and the second is the row. I also understand that the code isn't able to see past `0,1`. I'm just at a loss as to how to get it to see the rest of the sheet after trying other solutions of the same problem.

Comment: are you sure it's not first row and then column?

Comment: Why do you think this causes due to selenium??? what is the role of selenium here??

Comment: I think its first column then row from what I read in another solution about the same issue 

    public Cell getCell(int column,
                        int row)

Comment: Well the only link with selenium is when I access the page and pass the variable in after reading the cell so the issue perhaps is not with Selenium, i'll remove Selenium from the title

Comment: which library are you using?

Comment: I'm using jxl   import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

Comment: are you sure that the the column is 2? I think that it's 1 because it start from 0, just like rows

Comment: @GianniB.so 0,1 picks up 1000483 so I would assume 0,2 would pick up 1000484. I believe 2 is the row and 0 is the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sh1.getRows()` returns 3. As loop starts from 0,  `sh1.getRows()` needs to be decremented by 1 (as below). Below loop works fine and returns value properly.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;

public class Excel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File src = new File("c:/filepath.xls");

        try {
            String data1;
            Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(src);
            Sheet sh1 = wb.getSheet(0);


            for (int rows = 1; rows < sh1.getRows(); rows++)  {
                for (int column = 0; column <= sh1.getColumns()-1; column++) {

                    Cell a2 = sh1.getCell(column, rows);
                    data1 = a2.getContents().trim();
                    System.out.println(data1);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }



}
```

The above code works and fetches the date without error

Comment: Thanks for your code, unfortunately that still gives me an exception. However when I change it to (rows, 1) it gives  me 1000483. The print out for the rows when it fails gives me 2.

Comment: Also would it not be column and then row? Looking into the getCell method it shows - public Cell getCell(int column, int row);

Comment: I have modified the loop to run as column then row. But this depend how we need the data. I guess in your case it should return username and password so it should be column then row

Comment: Thanks again :) -  So you're correct it works when Row = 1 and column = 0. When I change Row to be 2 I dont enter the for loop as .getRows is always 2. I think my issue is .getRows is always returning 2 and how do I get that to see more of the sheet?

Comment: So it looks like I was just being silly, I've included more data in the spreadsheet. You've solved my problem so I'll mark it as solved. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I use the same data with you, and I could get `1000484` value through my code.

Here is my code :

```
package com.jason.xls;

import java.io.File;
import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;

public class XlsParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String path = "/home/coder/filepath.xls";
        System.out.println(readUserNameFromXls(path));
    }

    public static String readUserNameFromXls(final String path) {
        File file = new File(path);
        try {
            Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(file);
            Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet(0);
            Cell a2 = sheet.getCell(0, 2);
            return a2.getContents().trim();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
      }
 }
```

I download `jxl.jar` from [jxl.jar download here](http://download.csdn.net/detail/likai22/534250)

My code result is : [Code Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6HI6.png)

Comment: Thats strange, the only differences I can see is your method returns null and mine returns a String but I would still expect your code to complain about the outofbounds exception. Unless there is something different with your Excel?

Comment: Also why do you not have to catch the Biff exception?

Comment: I modify my code and catch BiffException and IOException, but I also get the correct answer, maybe my xls file is different from yours?